# Cryptography Pseudo random

Tags: python, random, cryptography

Going through some CTFs tasks I stumbled upon interesting  challenge. Following programme will take in flag text file containing single line of random alphanum characters (flag). Will run it though random character rotation and return a string

```
import random,string

flag = "FLAG:"+open("flag", "r").read()[:-1]
encflag = ""
random.seed("random")
for c in flag:
  if c.islower():
    #rotate number around alphabet a random amount
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('a'))
  elif c.isupper():
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('A')+random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('A'))
  elif c.isdigit():
    encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('0')+random.randrange(0,10))%10 + ord('0'))
  else:
    encflag += c
print "Unguessably Randomized Flag: "+encflag
```

Output : `BNZQ:1l36de9583w5516fv3b8691102224f3e`

Anyone can explain this can be solved?

Comment: I guess you could try to reverse it , since you know the `seed` ( "random" ) and part of the unencrypted string ( "FLAG:" ) . Seeing the output i imagine the encrypted text should be an md5 hash ( 32 lower alpanumeric characters )

Comment: @t.m.adam OK, as it is all digits & lowercase and has more digits than lowercase chars I'll give you that the result should likely consist of 32 hexadecimals, and therefore could well be a hash value (I don't have python running here).

Comment: *"Anyone can explain this can be solved?"* - what's the issue here? I don't see what's there to solve. Do you want to reverse it?

Answer (score 1):

As the random is seeded it should generate the same stream of ranges. So you can use the same function but you should change:

```
encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('a'))
```

into

```
encflag += chr((ord(c)-ord('a')-random.randrange(0,26))%26 + ord('a'))
//                change here -^
```

for all of the three lines.

This should work - until somebody puts a different, more efficient algorithm in the place of `random` at least, changes the handling of the seed, etc.

---

This is a bad stream cipher implemented using `random`, don't use it for anything serious. And, as using a non-cryptographic RNG instead of a stream cipher is rather stupid even for crypto demo code, I would not use it for learning purposes either.

Comment: To be precise, this is a variant of the Vigenère cipher with a pseudo-randomly generated key as long as the plaintext.